# Term to describe a collection of expenses you didn't think of

Tags: terminology, business-language, finance

When making out a expense chart for example I know there is a term (as I have seen it before) where you can put it in for expenses that may come up that you initially didn't think of - it's not `miscellaneous` as that still describes items, just items that don't really need their own line item.

Does anyone know the term I am talking about?

Comment: A common term in such contexts is ***sundries*** - which in the context of expense claim forms, for example, are rarely itemised individually.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn't that pretty much the same as miscellaneous?

Comment: In some contexts, yes. But as you imply yourself, an expense claim form might have separate sections for, say, *Travel, Accommodation, Food & Drink, Miscellaneous*, within each of which you're expected to *itemise* each expense as incurred. And that same form might also have a single entry called *Sundries* where you *don't* have to itemise the sub-elements. Imho it's extremely unlikely any forms designer would reverse those two "headings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "incidental" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are looking for the term 'contingency'.

Contingency expenses (or a contingency in the singular) are expenses incurred due to emergencies, unforseen events or other circumstances beyond the control of a person.

An incidental expense is one of the meanings for the contingency as stated in the Oxford Dictionary.

[Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contingency)

Comment: Hmmmm.... don't think that was it. I'm thinking more along the lines of things you just forget to budget for...... like because of all the little things that come up there has got to be things you will forget and thus it's good to budget some extra side money for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

"Miscellaneous Expenses" is the typical Income Statement item line title.

This is what we always had through all my accounting classes.